# Neo4j 1.8.1 ExecutionEngine constructor changes

Tags: java, neo4j

I just upgraded from using Neo4j 1.8 to 1.8.1 and noticed that there has been a change to the ExecutionEngine constructor contract. The [ExcecutionEngine(GraphDatabaseService)](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8.1/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionEngine.html#ExecutionEngine%28org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService%29) constructor is no longer available.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import org.neo4j.cypher.CypherException;
import org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;

public class CypherQueryExecutionService {
    private final ExecutionEngine executionEngine;

    public CypherQueryExecutionService(GraphDatabaseService 
graphDatabaseService) {
        executionEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService);
    }
...
```

POM extract:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>static-web</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

If there are no quick fixes, could you then please provide an example of using the StringLogger correctly?
In our case we are using logback over SLF4J.

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: use new ExecutionEngine(gdb, StringLogger.SYSTEM)

Comment: Thanks, I went for new ExecutionEngine(gdb, StringLogger.DEV_NULL). Will the missing constructor return in 1.9?

Comment: Actually the constructor is there for the java version of ExecutionEngine.